# Elections page not working on mobiles?

Tags: bug, elections

I generally visit this site on my mobile phone, a Samsung Galaxy Note3. However the elections page does not seem to have a mobile version like most of the site and the desktop page that is available is not working, at least on my phone (I'm using the Chrome mobile browser).

Firstly could others please check to see if this is unique to my phone as I don't have another phone handy to check with. And secondly if it's not just me can this be raised with the devs?

Until I get chance to visit the site on a desktop I cannot vote. This seems to be a problem.

---

**UPDATE**

This seems to be strictly limited to the Chrome browser. At jmorts request I tried the default phone's browser and it worked.

Comment: Are you able to try a different browser?

Comment: Just tried with the default phone browser and it worked.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Moto G using Chrome, which is the default browser. I just assumed it was a feature not a bug..

Comment: Works fine on Mobile Chrome on my iPhone 5! Do you let Chrome update itself?

Comment: Always, it's up to date at the moment, I checked.

Comment: @enderland have a dig through the apps, it might be buried but Android has another browser that ships before the manufacturers install anything on it. AFAIK they can't remove it so it should be on your phone somewhere.